# Excel How do I make this macro work on all workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I want this macro to work in all workbooks but it only works in the workbook that I've created "book1.xlsm", and when I transfer the macro to Personel.xlsb it doesn't work, Can anyone help me with this?

```
Sub SendSelectedCells_inOutlookEmail()
Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strTempHTMLFile As String
Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objTextStream As Object
Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strSig As String

'Copy the selection
Set objSelection = Selection
Selection.Copy

'Paste the copied selected ranges into a temp worksheet
Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Keep the values, column widths and formats in pasting
With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With

'Save the temp worksheet as a HTML file
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)

'Create a new email
Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Read the HTML file data and insert into the email body
Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)
objNewEmail.Display
strSig = objNewEmail.HTMLBody
objNewEmail.HTMLBody = objTextStream.ReadAll & strSig

'You can specify the new email recipients, subjects here using the following lines:
'objNewEmail.To = "johnsmith@datanumen.com"
'objNewEmail.Subject = "DataNumen Products"
'objNewEmail.Send --> directly send out this email

objTextStream.Close
objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
```

End Sub

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very descriptive - exactly what does it do instead of working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new file you need to set an Object Reference to the Microsoft Outlook Object Library otherwise the line `Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application` will produce a compile error. How-to guide [here](https://www.educba.com/vba-outlook/)

Comment: Thanks that fixed it :).

Comment: Glad I could help! Next time you should add the error message to the question to make it easier for people to understand